# C++, OpenGL clipping

Tags: c++, opengl, clipping

I'm making a cube based game (everything is a cube) and currently trying to optimize it by not drawing the stuff outside the field of view.

The following applies only to the x and y planes, I'll worry about the z later... so only side clipping for now.

I know my own position and rotation in the world and the position of every single cube there is, so the idea is to compare the z and x rotation angles of the player and the cube relative to the player and only display the cubes within with a defined range.

Code time:

```
// this is how I turn
float zrotrad = (float)zrot*DEG2RAD;
float view_limit = .4;

// distance between the cube and me
float dist_x = box_x-xpos;
float dist_y = box_y-ypos;
float dist_z = box_z-zpos;

// total distance (I'll use fast sqrt later)
float dist_tot = sqrt(dist_x*dist_x+dist_y*dist_y);

float angle = acos(dist_y/dist_tot);
// need to add 2 pies because acos returns a value [0,2PI]
float zcuberot = dist_x<0?2*PI-angle:angle;

if(zcuberot > zrotrad-view_limit && zcuberot < zrotrad+view_limit)
{
    drawcube(box_x, box_y, box_z);
}
```

As you've probably understood, there's a problem around 0 degrees, since my left field view limit becomes negative and the zcuberot gets 2 pies added to it the range gets messed up. Same story for the 359 degrees - actually less because of the `view_limit = .4`.

I've been messing around for 2 days with this and feel like such a dumbass for asking this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be much, much faster (and less error-prone) to implement an **octree**. You will then be able to cull all non-visible cubes by discarding the parts of the octree that do not intersect with your viewing frustum. You won't have to perform this test for every single cube, and you'll be able to reduce the test to comparing a single larger cube against 6 planes.

Compared to what you have, an octree will be a few *orders of magnitude* faster.

You can find a good deal of information about octrees on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) and [Flipcode](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Introduction_To_Octrees.shtml), among other places.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is clip against the frustum planes. 
Here you'll find pretty much everything you need to know about the frustum and how to extract the planes from the view matrix, and even some code to test if a cube is within the view volume: http://www.crownandcutlass.com/features/technicaldetails/frustum.html

Comment: Very good idea, will implement right away... after I get those frustrum volume values somehow.